# PDFBox Vector Rendering

Tags: java, pdfbox

PDFBox sometimes renders vectors as image, sometimes keep them as they are.. How does PDFBox decide to render or not? Is there any way to force PDFBox to not render vector into images?

Comment: These might be transparency groups and patterns. These are first rendered as images. And no, you can't force it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr What if I compile PDFBox by myself, and break the condition line where PDFBox decide to convert vector elements into image format? I mean make it always choose to vector format... Does it possible?

Comment: It's open source so you're welcome to play with it if you have a lot of time... but I doubt it is easy. It's not just a switch to turn on or off. For patterns it would mean that you'd have to have to draw each pattern tile itself; for transparency groups / softmasks it would mean you'd lose the transparency effect, unless SVG graphics has some feature that supports that somehow.