# PDF to SVG rendering issues using PDFBox and Apache Batik

Tags: java, svg, pdfbox, batik

I am using a combination of PDFBox with Apache Batik in order to render PDF pages as SVG documents. Most of them work fine, but I have some issues when rendering specific images into SVG.

This is the code I use. It is mostly based on the post over [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527687/pdf2svg-apache-batik-textasshape-option-causes-fonts-get-converted).

```
public void extractBookSvg(File pdfFile) throws Exception {
    // ... preliminary business actions

    SVGGeneratorContext ctx = createContext();
    SVGGraphics2D g = null;

    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile, MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(2147483648l))) {
        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int pageNr = 0;
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            long startTimeForPage = System.currentTimeMillis();

            g = createGraphics(ctx);
            renderer.renderPageToGraphics(pageNr, g, 3.47222f);

            pageNr++;
            try (OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(os)) {

                g.stream(out, true);

                //... do other business actions 
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        pdfFile.delete();

        if (g != null) {
            g.finalize();
            g.dispose();
        }
    }
}

private SVGGraphics2D createGraphics(SVGGeneratorContext ctx) {
    SVGGraphics2D g2d = new CustomSVGGraphics2D(ctx, false);
    return g2d;
}

private SVGGeneratorContext createContext() {
    DOMImplementation impl = GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
    String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    Document myFactory = impl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);

    SVGGeneratorContext ctx = SVGGeneratorContext.createDefault(myFactory);
    return ctx;
}

public static class CustomSVGGraphics2D extends SVGGraphics2D {

    public CustomSVGGraphics2D(SVGGeneratorContext generatorCtx, boolean textAsShapes) {
        super(generatorCtx, textAsShapes);
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicsConfiguration getDeviceConfiguration() {
        return new CustomGraphicsConfiguration();
    }
}

private static final class CustomGraphicsConfiguration extends GraphicsConfiguration {

    @Override
    public AffineTransform getNormalizingTransform() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicsDevice getDevice() {
        return new CustomGraphicsDevice();
    }

    @Override
    public AffineTransform getDefaultTransform() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ColorModel getColorModel(int transparency) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ColorModel getColorModel() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public java.awt.Rectangle getBounds() {
        return null;
    }
}

private static final class CustomGraphicsDevice extends GraphicsDevice {
    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIDstring() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicsConfiguration[] getConfigurations() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicsConfiguration getDefaultConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the issue comes when rendering images: they either do not get rendered at all (show up as black boxes), or on some images that have opacity lower than 1, they are shown with opacity 1.

Here is an example of both cases:

[PDF render of transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gduSK.png)

[SVG render of transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFOvb.png)

[These images do not get rendered at all in SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF2Ue.png)

[How they actually show in the SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCc82.png)

However, if I directly render those pages as images (using BufferedImage instead Graphics2D), they both render fine (with a lower quality than the svg, of course).

Also, I have tried debugging the PDF with the PDFDebugger utility, and those images do not appear in the resources XObject list of the page, and I can't seem to find them nowhere else.

My questions are:

- how can I find out if the issue comes from the way PDFBox renders into the Graphics2D object, or it comes from the way Batik does the SVG generation?
- is there a way to make sure those images are properly displayed at generation time? Because I see no errors in the logs.
- if so, what could be the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: You could try `BufferedImage.createGraphics()` to see whether it renders correctly in graphics. But it does, the standard rendering does that under the hood. So the real question is whether Batik / SVG supports alpha masks, transparency etc.

Comment: The images are there, but a level deeper. Have a look at `Root/Pages/Kids/[6]/Kids/[0]/Kids/[0]/Kids/[0]/Resources/XObject/Fm1/Resources/XObject/Im0`.

Comment: I did some debugging and also had a look into the Batik source code... The problem is that Batik ignores a Paint object, which paints a softmask in PDFBox. The `Paint.createContext()` method is never called. A look in Batik at `SVGPaint.toSVG(Paint paint)` shows that only Color, GradientPaint and TexturePaint are supported.

I also found a bug in PDFBox that produces an NPE when rendering annotations with Batik (but it doesn't matter much as Batik can't be used anyway) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4248

Comment: Hello Tilman. First of all, thank you for your help and interest regarding this issue. I have sent an email to the Batik developers mailing list, in hope I get an answer regarding if they will add support for this or not.

Comment: It may be difficult. I don't know much about SVG but the V is for vector. The Paints that PDFBox implemented work on the pixel level. The implementation is in `PaintContext.getRaster()` which work on little stripes, so I suspect that Batik would have to return a lot of tiny images.